# General Error: 1005 - Migración de Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

Tengo un error muy extraño de una tabla intermedia de productos y etiquetas.
Resulta que si le cambio el nombre a la tabla la migración se completa satisfactoriamente. Pero si le dejo el nombre que quiero ingresarle... error.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer('status')->default(2); // 0 => Disapproved, 1 => Approved, 2 => Pending
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('tag_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
    Schema::dropIfExists('tag_product');
}
```

Si el nombre de la tabla lo modifico a "tag_product2", la migración es unánime. Si al dejo tal cual está no funciona.

Aclaro que por cada prueba que hago elimino todas las tablas de la base de datos. También, ejecuté el comando "`php artisan cache:clear`" y reinicié mi computadora.

Acá dejo una captura del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dije, si cambio el nombre a "tag_product2" funciona perfecto. Ya revisé y no hay otra tabla con el mismo nombre.

Si modifico el nombre...

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer('status')->default(2); // 0 => Disapproved, 1 => Approved, 2 => Pending
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('asdasdasd', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

FUNCIONA:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La tabla products existe y la llave primaria es bigIncrements?

Comment: Puede ser que no usaste el mismo tipo de dato, es decir en este caso todas tus llaves primariasdeben ser `bigIncrements` y las foráneas `unsignedBigInteger` deberías checar la tabla `mercadonegro que marca no se puede crear`

Comment: Si, como dije, si cambio el nombre de la tabla intermedia funciona perfecto.

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste los tipos de datos que te mencionamos?

Comment: Prueba con `product_tag`, la convención de laravel para la tabla pivote es por orden alfabético, así que si ese nombre te funciona, estarías bien con las convenciones. Y `mercadonegro`  es otra tabla o es la base de datos? Podrías mostrar la migración de la tabla `products`?

Comment: Si, el codigo es correcto. Modifico el nombre y funciona.

Comment: Probé con product_tag y funcionó. No sabia lo de la conversión en orden alfabético. Lo voy a dejar así. Lo que no entiendo es porqué no funciona específicamente con el nombre "tag_product"

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Sí, tampoco entiendo por que no funciona con cualquier otro nombre, pues debería hacerlo. Lo de las convenciones te facilita el desarrollo, pero no es obligación seguirlas. Es raro.